# Disable default caps lock tooltip in IE input

Tags: html, internet-explorer, input, capslock

In my login dialog on my password input, I got a tooltip in the `Internet Explorer`, when my focus is on the input and caps lock is activated (all other browsers have not such an default tooltip). I would like to remove this default tooltip **without any javascript**. Is there an attribute or something else?

```html
Password: <input type="password" required>
```

Screenshot with the tooltip in IE:

[image]

Comment: It can't be done without JavaScript, although WITH JavaScript it's apparently quite trivial.

Comment: You can disable it **only** with JavaScript --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj128374(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @JuOliveira Ok, if there is no other way to do this I havn't got another choise... thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that code is also on the documentation link I posted above and it's what solves your problem :) welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a solution according to the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj128374(v=vs.85).aspx).**

Turns automatic caps lock warning off for validated password input fields.

```
if (document.msCapsLockWarningOff == false) {
  document.msCapsLockWarningOff = true;
}
```